Странная ошибка с созданием pb файла (grpc)
Я практикую grpc на go и при создании pb файла командой:
PS C:\Users\lisis\Goproject\src\nana> protoc --proto_path=./proto --go_out=. --go_grpc_out=. ./proto/product.proto

у меня вышла ошибка :
--go_out: main/proto/product.pb.go: unparsable Go source: 7:13: expected ';', found '='
    1   // Code generated by protoc-gen-go. DO NOT EDIT.
    2   // versions:
    3   //      protoc-gen-go v1.35.1
    4   //      protoc        v5.28.2
    5   // source: product.proto  (там она дальше продолжается, но не думаю что нужна)

А это код который я преобразовал:
syntax = "proto3";
option go_package = "main/proto;name=product";

package product;

service ProductService {
  rpc GetProduct (GetProductRequest) returns (Product) {}
}

message GetProductRequest {
  string id = 1;
}

message Product {
  string id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  string description = 3;
  double price = 4;
} 


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос

У Вас вот тут ошибка:
rpc GetProduct (GetProductRequest) returns (Product) {}

должно быть
rpc GetProduct (GetProductRequest) returns (Product);

